# Trying to get chat window to get focus when called from multiple pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web site that I am working on that has a Click to Chat button in the header. When clicking that button, we want a chat window to open up. So far no problem. The issue comes in the following scenario.

1. User is on a.html.
2. User press Click to Chat.
3. Chat with Customer Service.
4. User clicks on some other link on the site and goes to b.html.
5. User presses Click to Chat.
6. New chat window with a different Customer Service person opens up.

When the user goes to b.html we lose the javascript reference to the window that was open and not sure how to get it or if it is even possible due to security browser restrictions.

```
1: function openChatWindow() {
2:    try {
3:        var chatWindow = window.open('', 'chatWindow', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, left=200, top=200, width=700, height=675');
4:        if (chatWindow && !chatWindow.closed && chatWindow.document.body.innerHTML != '') {
5:            chatWindow.focus();
6:        } else {
7:            chatWindow = window.open('/WebChat/default.asp', 'chatWindow', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, left=200, top=200, width=700, height=675');
8:        }
9:    } catch (e) { }
10:    return false;
11: }
12:</script>
```

The hope that was line 3 would work, I saw some posts from other StackOverflow comments that led to this assumption, but so far no good. When I try and access it on line 4, I get a security error:

```
exception:SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin 
"my.server.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Anyone have any other creative ideas on a way to resolve this or if this is something that is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: i would make the open chat button check to see if there is a chat in-progress and if so, alert the user that they already have a chat and abort; not launching another popup. to see if there is a chat already, use localStorage in the popup to set `localStorage.chat=1` _onload_ and _onunload_, `localStorage.chat=0`. i don't think you can focus() it once the opener closes, but you can at least complain...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't write the chat code so if there is a way to do get a session id, then I don't have to care if there is a window open and I can just open a new window each time and have it reload the web chat session.

Comment: you could save that session info to localStorage in the same manner. it's possible to follow my advice without altering the code in the popup, just the code around it...

Comment: Right. I just need to figure out the session information stuff so I know if there is a way to get and load based on id. The storing the session info is the easy part. Was hoping there was a way to do it with just javascript, but it sounds like it is a security issue and that is why there is no straight forward way to achieve this.  Thanks for your help.